# cf login Credentials were rejected, please try again

Tags: cloud-foundry

cf login is not working even if the password has been provided. It is again asking for password.

```
C:\McD\covid\cur>cf login -u passcode -p aLfKrLidQp
API endpoint: https://api.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com

Warning: Your targeted API's version (3.83.0) is less 
than the minimum supported API version (3.85.0). Some 
commands may not function correctly.


Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.

Password:
```

Comment: Maybe that means it thinks the password is wrong... or that the mentioned API mismatch is a problem. Are you sure both are really OK?

Comment: Run `cf -v login ...` and include that output instead. That will show the request being sent and the response. It could be that your password is just wrong, but this would let you see if there's an unexpected response from the server.